# Reverse this array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Array - from helpful comment by user Barry Houdini (great name too)

---

You can use PERCENTILE function in an array formula and get the result in one go, e.g. with data in A2:A29 try this array formula in B2

`=MATCH(A2,PERCENTILE(A$2:A$29,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)`

confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and copy down

---

I should like to reverse this; as for my purposes a LOW score is better.

It was not as simple as changing to {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Does `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` work if you change the [MATCH function's](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) `match_type` parameter from -1 (*descending*) to 1 (*ascending*)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does, sort of - but now introduces errors on the smallest values that I didn't get with original array.

Comment: @pnuts you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that to reverse that array (?) formula, you will first have to reverse and shift the arrayed constants from 5→1 to 0→4. The [MATCH` function's](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) *match_type* parameter will also have to be changes from -1 (*descending*) to 1 (*ascending*).

[image: Percentile Match]

The formula in D2 is,

`=MATCH(A2,PERCENTILE(A$2:A$29,{0,1,2,3,4}/5), 1)`

Fill down as necessary.

Two things to note:

1. I got the same results whether this was entered as an array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) or as a standard formula. I suspect that only a standard formula is actually necessary.
2. The `MATCH` function's *match_type* parameter's default is *1* so it can actually be left out of the formula altogether. e.g. `=MATCH(A2,PERCENTILE(A$2:A$29,{0,1,2,3,4}/5))`

Comment: Sorry @pnuts, Didn't see your comment before posting this. Will be deleting it as soon as the OP sees it (some vague extra info included).